# According to islam.. Can girls go out of their home for the sake of refreshment?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, women

My brother says that I can not go to my friend's house. According to him it is not necessary. But I think girls have a right to have some kind of enjoyment or refreshment. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Women are allowed to go out. The Prophet (ﷺ) used to take his wives out on journeys with him [even though he could have left them to stay at home]. And there are many examples other examples of women in the Prophet's (ﷺ) time going out and about.

Women can visit masajid for worship, they can go out for necessities such as to the local markets to buy food or clothes, they can visit their families and friends, etc. They just need to make sure that wherever they go, it is a halal environment.

Having said that, there's no doubt that staying at home is best for women. Allah (ﷻ) told the wives of the Prophet [who are the role models for the rest of Muslim women]: وقرن في بيوتكن ولا تبرجن تبرج الجاهلية الأولى (And stay in your houses, and do not display yourselves like that of the times of ignorance...) - Qur'an 33:33.